# Problem communicating with Xiaomi M365 using a serial port in a Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, xiaomi

I'm trying to communnicate with a Xiaomi M365 scooter using a serial port connected to a Raspberry Pi in the port /dev/ttyUSB0. To test it I'm using Python scripts, for example, in this one I'm trying to execute a command to turn on the rear light:

```
import serial
import time
with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1) as ser:
time.sleep(1);
ser.write("55aa0320037d025aff".decode('hex'));
```

The problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes not, it can take me up to 10 executions to actually turn on the light, this also occurs with any other command like the one to turn off the rear light or the one to get the scooter's data.

I think the problem could be related with the way that the data is written to the serial port in the Raspberry, or how the Raspberry manage the serial port, but although I have been searching for days I cannot find how to fix it.

Just to give more info about the issue, if I connect the USB, connected to the Xiaomi M365, to a machine with windows, instead to a Raspberry, everything works as expected always.

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Best regards.

Comment: How did you connect the serial port to the scooter?  Maybe there's some problem there.